# Error en la conexion de ruby on rails y postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Veran tengo mi proyecto rails en digital ocean y la base de datos en AWS.
La cuestión es que funciona la migración pero cuando quiero entrar a la pagina me sale error 500, reviso el log de producción y me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instale postgresql en mi servidor y cuando ejecuto otra vez me sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que es un error interno pero no se cual necesito ayuda
Gracias

Comment: Fijate en tu conexion a postgres, parece que estas accediendo via local, otro detalle es que  debes habilitar la conexion adecuada para ese "usuario" , fijate en tu archivo pg_hba.conf

Comment: y como lo hago eso ?

Comment: debes anlizar que lineas hay en ese archivo (pg_hba.conf) y si no hay una entrada para tu "usuario" debes agregarla

Answer (score 0):

debes agregar unas lineas como esta en el archivo `pg_hba.conf` de postgres

```
local   all             usuario                                     md5
host    all             usuario             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```